# Minimizing Cost of a Box

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

EDIT: Solved. There was a typo on the worksheet for the cost of the side.

So a rectangular box with a volume of $320 ft^3$ is constructed with a square base and top. Cost per sqft for Bottom is $\$0.15$, Top is $\$0.10$, and Side is $\$0.0025$. What are dimensions that would minimize cost?

These are my root equations to build the Cost formula from:

Cost $= B+T+4S$, $L=W$ (because square base), Bot= $W^2$, Top= $W^2$, Side=$4WH$, $V=HW^2$ so $H=V/W^2$

With the numbers plugged in I get:

$C = .15W^2 + .10W^2 + (.0025)(4)(W)(320/W^2)$ or $(3.2/W)$

$C' = .3W + .2W - 3.2W^{-2}$

$C' = .5W - 3.2W^{-2}$

Then solving for the CP I get

$.5W -3.2W^{-2} = 0$

$(-3.2/(w^{2}) = -.5W$

$-3.2 = -.5W^3$

$6.4 = W^3$

$W = 1.86$

With $W$ plugged back into equation for Height I have:

$H = 320 / (1.86^2)$

$H = 92.5$

So my final dimensions would be $L=1.86, W=1.86$ and $H=92.5$ to minimize cost.

The only issue is my calc professor provided answers for the final prep questions and her final dimensions are $L=4, W=4$ and $H=20$. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: My guess is that the cost of the side is not 0.0025, but in fact 0.025

Comment: Excellent catch! There's an ink smear over one of the 0's in 0.0025 of the worksheet that I thought was just a typo.  I guess the actual cost after correction is 0.025 which gives me the same numbers that she's getting. Thanks for the keen observation.